# How to get Oracle Coherence Clusters synchronized?

Tags: java, oracle, distributed-caching, oracle-coherence

I'm looking for an option to have my cache data being replicated and synchronized across multiple Oracle Coherence clusters.

Unfortunately, I have no chance to upgrade a Java version I'm currently using, so the Oracle Coherence [Federated Caching](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/coherence/administer/replication.htm#COHAG5388) feature is not available for me - Oracle Coherence 12.2.1 [requires](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/coherence/install/install_java.htm#COHIN4995) JDK 1.8 or later.

Are there any other alternatives for the **active-active** cache synchronization topology?

Comment: It's related to distributed caching, so I don't think Database Admins could help with that.

Comment: Hmm you are right, sorry. I will retract my vote.

Answer (score 0):

The Coherence incubator project has an active-active replication example here that you can follow: http://coherence-community.github.io/coherence-incubator/11.2.1-SNAPSHOT/pushreplicationpattern/active-active-example.html